# How to "SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE" using JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I tried to find a documentation for it, but failed. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to add MySQL-style hints to jOOQ queries:

#### Using `.hint()`

jOOQ allows for passing "hints" to `SELECT` statements via the [`.hint()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SelectFromStep.html#hint-java.lang.String-) method as explained here in the manual:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/oracle-hints

Applying the `SQL_NO_CACHE` hint to the example given in the manual, you'd get:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(field1, field2)
   .hint("SQL_NO_CACHE")
   .from(table1)
   .fetch();
```

#### Using plain SQL

You could use plain SQL to tweak the first field in your `SELECT` clause to contain the hint using [`DSL.field(String)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-). E.g.

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(DSL.field("SQL_NO_CACHE {0}", field1.getDataType(), field1), field2)
   .from(table1)
   .fetch();
```

#### Using `ExecuteListener` or `VisitListener`

You could inject an [`ExecuteListener`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.6/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-execute-listeners/) or a [`VisitListener`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.6/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-sql-transformation/) into your configuration in order to transform all relevant SQL query strings to contain the hint right after the `SELECT` keyword. This will probably be a bit of overkill in your case, but it's worth mentioning this as an option to this kind of problem.

Comment: I like to use `.hint` method. Tweaking with plain SQL looks like an anti-pattern to me, and I agree with your comment abount using `ExecuteListener` or `VisitListener`. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Stanley시크Yeo: Plain SQL may be a necessary means to get some string into the jOOQ AST at the right position. In this case, there's a better, official option, but in other cases, you may not find any such option (yet)